# Is it better to use exceptions in a "validation" class or return status codes?

Tags: python, validation, exception, status

Suppose I'm creating a class to validate a number, like "Social Security" in US (just as an example of a country-based id). There are some rules to validate this number that comes from an input in a html form in a website.

I thinking about creating a simple class in Python, and a public `validate` method. This `validate` returns `True` or `False`, simply. This method will call other small private methods (like for the first 'x' numbers if there is a different rule), each one returning `True` or `False` as well.

Since this is really simple, I'm thinking of using boolean status codes only (if it's valid or not, don't need meaningful messages about what is wrong).

I've been reading [some articles about using exceptions](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2003/10/13.html), and I would like to know your opinion in my situation: would using exceptions would be a good idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If an input is either valid or not, then just return the boolean. There's nothing exceptional about a validation test encountering an invalid value.

Comment: `raise NeitherValidNorInvalidException('D:')`

Comment: Thats what I'm thinking of at first. Thats why Im asking for more opinions, maybe someone can see something I'm not aware of. Thanks.

Comment: Well, to expand a bit further. Suppose I had a method that uses the value, say ErasePersonalIdentity(ssn), then it would be reasonable that ssn should be valid. If an invalid ssn were provided, then raising an InvalidSSNException would be appropriate. The point being, if an operation requires valid input, then an exception should be triggered when invalid input is provided. If an operation is validating input, then there is no exception.

Comment: is spot on. Remember, if you want an exception you can always `assert Validator.is_valid(ssn)`.

Answer (score 11):

This is a very old question but since the only answer - IMO - is not applicable to Python, here comes my take on it.

---

Exceptions in Python is something many programmers new to the language have difficulties dealing with. Compared to other languages, Python differs significantly in how exceptions are used: in fact **Python routinely uses exceptions for flow control**.

The canonical example is the `for` loop: you will certainly agree that there is nothing "uniquely bizarre" about the loop exhausting its iterations (indeed that's what **all** loops do, unless broken)... yet rather than checking in advance if there are still values to process, Python keeps on trying reading values from the iterable, and failing that, rises the [`StopIterator` exception](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration), which in turn is catch by the `for` expression and make the code exiting the loop.

Furthermore, it is idiomatic in Python to go by the **EAFP** (it's Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission = `try-except`) rather than LBYL (Look Before You Leap = `if not A, B or C then`).

In this regard, csj's answer is correct for C or Java but is irrelevant for Python (whose **exceptions are seldom "exceptional" in nature**).

Another factor to consider - though - is the scenario in which user data is invalid but you fail to act on the validation function outcome:

- with a `return statement`, failing to process the `False` value will result in having your non-valid data sent down the pipeline,
- contrarily, if you were to `raise` an Exception, failing to catch it would result in the exception propagating through your stack eventually resulting in your code to halt.

While the second option might seems scary at first, it is still the right road to take: if data is invalid, there is no sense in passing it further down the line... it will most probably introduce difficult-to-track bugs later on in the flow and you will have also missed the chance to fix a bug in your code (failing to act on non-valid data).

Again. **Using exceptions is the *pythonic* way to do** (but it does not apply to most other languages) as also stated in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1152556/146792) and in the [zen of python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Errors should never pass silently.
>
> Unless explicitly silenced.

HTH!

Comment: I couldn't imagine a situation where failing to process the False result would happen. Do you mean typo or something? If a careless developer confuses the output of a return statement for example, somewhere, someday, an error would pass silently, but with an exception, this wouldn't happen? What do you think of the `assert` [solution provided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671450/is-it-better-to-use-exceptions-in-a-validation-class-or-return-status-codes#comment3865104_3671488) by @katrielalex?

Comment: Q1: I am imagining some sort of typo, yes. Q2: `assert`s are a terrible way to do flow control (apart from unit testing maybe). For one, all assert statements can be disabled if the python interpreter is run in optimisation mode (python -O). They are useful in debugging mode, but raise is 99% the way to go...

Comment: Careless developer? Everyone makes mistakes. Besides, that is why exceptions were invented in the first place, that everyone got tired of checking exit codes in every line, as it tends to make code unreadable, and it is easy to forget to check one out of 20 things that can go wrong. With exceptions, such errors can often be noticed within minutes, by the very developer who wrote it.