# To ask permission or apologize?

Tags: c#, python, performance

I come from a python background, where it's often said that it's easier to apologize than to ask permission. Specifically given the two snippets:

```
if type(A) == int:
  do_something(A)
else:
  do_something(int(A))

try:
  do_something(A)
except TypeError:
  do_something(int(A))
```

Then under most usage scenarios the second one will be faster when A is usually an integer (assuming do_something needs an integer as input and will raise its exception fairly swiftly) as you lose the logical test from every execution loop, at the expense of a more costly exception, but far less frequently.

What I wanted to check was whether this is true in C#, or whether logical tests are fast enough compared to exceptions to make this a small corner case?

Oh and I'm only interested in release performance, not debug.

---

OK my example was too vague try this one:

Naive solution:

```
return float(A) % 20 # coerse A to a float so it'll only fail if we actually don't
                     # have anything that can be represented as a real number.
```

Logic based solution:

```
if isinstance(A, Number): # This is cheaper because we're not creating a new
    return A % 20         # object unless we really have to.
else:
    return float(A) %20
```

Exception based solution:

```
try: # Now we're doing any logical tests in the 99% of cases where A is a number
  return A % 20
except TypeError:
  return float(A) % 20
```

Examples using FSOs, database connections, or stuff over a network are better but a bit long-winded for a question.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312/what-is-the-real-overhead-of-try-catch-in-c. @Tobi's answer seems relevant to your question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Throwing exceptions should almost always be more expensive because it has a lot to remember, testing for a type on the other hand does not.

Comment: Can you give a scenario for C#? Because the one you provided for python isn't really common as C# is strong typed.

Comment: Even if you do check first, in Python (and, I would think, in C#) it is always a bad idea to do `if type(A) == int` - you should prefer `if isinstance(A, int)`.

Comment: General rule of thumb. Its worth asking permission if your going to need a lot of forgiveness. Otherwise just be forgiven.

Comment: @lvc generally I think you're right,k but there are circumstances where you want something to be a specific type, not a subtype, as you cannot guarantee that someone has not overwritten the method you want to use

Comment: Another related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1152541/117092

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Probably not. .NET exceptions are relatively expensive.

Several .NET functions offer both variants for this reason. (`int.TryParse`, which returns a success code is often recommended because it is faster than `int.Parse` which throws an exception on failure)

But the only answer that matters is what your own profiling data tells you.
If you need performance, then you need to measure, measure, measure.

Because what was fastest on *my* computer, with *my* code, with *my* version of the .NET framework, at *this* time may not be the fastest on your computer, with *your* code, with your version of the .NET framework at the time when you read it.

Comment: Could you please provide some evidence of 'Probably not. .NET exceptions are relatively expensive.'?

Comment: @Abdul: please read the last paragraph of my answer. Test it for yourself. But note that I said "relatively", because compared to a simple branch on a boolean value, exceptions are *very* expensive. But compared to most of what goes on in an application's lifetime, exceptions are typically not a problem.

Answer (score 8):

Exceptions in .NET are fairly heavyweight, so the philosophy in C# is to use exceptions only for exceptional situations, not for program flow.

The philosophy in C# is also geared towards checking all input received from external code before using it. Example:

```
public void Foo(int i)
{
    if (i == 0)           // validate input received from external code
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("i");
    }

    DoSomething(i);
}

public void Foo()
{
    DoSomething(1);
}

internal void DoSomething(int i)
{
    Debug.Assert(i != 0); // validate that i is not zero in DEBUG build
                          // assume that i is not zero in RELEASE build

    Console.WriteLine(42 / i);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As a rule of thumb, I would say that exceptions should not be used for flow control. Use exceptions for exceptional circumstances - so if you do expect A to be an int, then your first approach is sensible. If it could be an int or a string, the second is more readable.

Performance-wise there is a difference in a release build - sensible logical tests are certainly fast enough - so personally I would go for readability.

Comment: He specifically asked about performance, so talking about readability, no matter how true, is kind of missing the point.

Comment: @jalf: As I read the question it is 'How should I approach this problem in the C# way, based on the approaches I know from my Python background?' coupled with 'Which would provide better performance in a release build', so I'd have to disagree with that comment.

Comment: Sure. If you ignore the `[performance]` tag, the phrase "I'm only interested in release performance", and that he states that the exception version is faster in Python, and then asks "whether this is true in C#". Sure. Then performance is completely irrelevant

Comment: What about the rules-of-thumb tag? I was simply trying to provide a balanced answer. Clearly I'm not going to win you over, so we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Comment: You don't need to win me over. But answering the actual question asked by the OP would be preferable. ;)

Comment: The questioner is new to C# and is seeking advice from an experienced, knowledgeable C# user. If I were the questioner, or the random google searcher, it would be important that I have full knowledge of the *incidental* consequences of my choice. When answering a question, it's common to note any caveats that the questioner was not aware of, but needs to know. Namely: using exceptions for flow control is frowned upon in C#.

Answer (score 3):

Exceptions should no be used as a "normal" execution flow control tool, and yes they are expensive.

Anyhow I think your question is slightly misguided, coming from python. C# is (or was?) a statically typed language which means that many scenarios similar to what you are proposing can be resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

http://paltman.com/2008/01/18/try-except-performance-in-python-a-simple-test/ has a similar test, except looking at has_key, which I'd expect to be (slightly) more expensive than type checking.

For the case of some large number of iterations where the key exists (so the exception is never thrown) it's about 25% faster, but still fairly fast. Where the key never exists it's about 1000% slower.

Now bearing in mind that type checking is faster than looking up a key, and that .Net exceptions are, as mentioned above, fairly heavyweight, you'd need A to be an integer the vast majority of the time before it's even potentially worthwhile.

But, as jalf mentioned earlier. Try it out and see.